# How to fix "400 Bad Request" rest-auth/registration/?

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, react-redux

I am using react, react redux for registration while django rest api to create user register serializers. I am a newbee. I am getting 404 bad request error every time i am trying to sign up?

First in django I created custoom user

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True

    def create_user(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, role_id, contact_num, opt_contact_num, citizenship_num, password=None):
        user = self.model(
            username=username,
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            role_id=role_id,
            contact_num=contact_num,
            opt_contact_num=opt_contact_num,
            citizenship_num=citizenship_num,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_staffuser(self,username, email, first_name, last_name, role_id, contact_num, opt_contact_num, citizenship_num, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            role_id=role_id,
            contact_num=contact_num,
            opt_contact_num=opt_contact_num,
            citizenship_num=citizenship_num,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, first_name, last_name, role_id, contact_num, opt_contact_num, citizenship_num, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            username=username,
            email=email,
            first_name="True",
            last_name="True",
            role_id=0,
            contact_num=contact_num,
            opt_contact_num=opt_contact_num,
            citizenship_num=citizenship_num,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

#custom user table
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    role_id = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    contact_num = PhoneNumberField(null=False, blank=False)
    opt_contact_num = PhoneNumberField(null=True, blank=True)
    citizenship_num = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = [ 'email','first_name','last_name', 'role_id', 'contact_num', 'opt_contact_num', 'citizenship_num' ]
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()

    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_admin

    def is_staff(self):
       return self.is_admin

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
       return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
       return self.is_admin

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

Then included Custom Register and details Serializer

```
class CustomRegisterSerializer(RegisterSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    email = serializers.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    last_name = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    role_id = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    contact_num = serializers.IntegerField(required=True)
    opt_contact_num = serializers.IntegerField(allow_null=True)
    citizenship_num = serializers.CharField(required=True)
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)
    password2 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    def get_cleaned_data(self):
        super(CustomRegisterSerializer, self).get_cleaned_data()

        return {
            'username': self.validated_data.get('username', ''),
            'email': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'first_name': self.validated_data.get('email', ''),
            'last_name': self.validated_data.get('last_name', ''),
            'role_id': self.validated_data.get('role_id', ''),
            'contact_num': self.validated_data.get('contact_num', ''),
            'opt_contact_num': self.validated_data.get('opt_contact_num', ''),
            'citizenship_num': self.validated_data.get('citizenship_num', ''),
            'password1': self.validated_data.get('password1', ''),
            'password2': self.validated_data.get('password2', ''),
        }

class CustomUserDetailsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','first_name', 'last_name', 'role_id', 'contact_num', 'opt_contact_num', 'citizenship_num')
        read_only_fields = ('username','email','first_name', 'last_name', 'role_id', 'contact_num', 'opt_contact_num', 'citizenship_num')
```

Changed settings.py this way,

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'
    ]
}

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'none'

ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = 'username'

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_EMAIL = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_UNIQUE_USERNAME = True
ACCOUNT_USER_EMAIL_FIELD = 'email'
ACCOUNT_LOGOUT_ON_GET = True

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'menu.User'

REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    "USER_DETAILS_SERIALIZER": "menu.api.serializers.CustomUserDetailsSerializer",
}

REST_AUTH_REGISTER_SERIALIZERS = {
    "REGISTER_SERIALIZER": "menu.api.serializers.CustomRegisterSerializer",
}

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = False

DATETIME_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

PHONENUMBER_DEFAULT_REGION = "NP"
```

I am using react and react redux for signing up user:

```
export const authSignup = (username, email, first_name, last_name, role_id, contact_num, opt_contact_num, citizenship_num, password1, password2) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(authStart());
    axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration/', {
      username: username,
      email: email,
      first_name: first_name,
      last_name: last_name,
      role_id: role_id,
      contact_num: contact_num,
      opt_contact_num: opt_contact_num,
      citizenship_num: citizenship_num,
      password1: password1,
      password2: password2,
    })
    .then(res => {
      const token = res.data.key;
      const expirationDate = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 3600 * 1000 * 24);
      localStorage.setItem('token', token);
      localStorage.setItem('username', username);
      localStorage.setItem('expirationDate', expirationDate);
      dispatch(getUserDetails(token, username));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      dispatch(authFail(err))
    })
  }
}
```

This is what signup form sends data:

```
Object
citizenship_num: "ajfahfl556"
confirm: "12345678"
contact_num: "9849829046"
email: "user@email.com"
first_name: "user"
last_name: "RMS"
opt_contact_num: undefined
password: "12345678"
role_id: "3"
userName: "user"
```

Comment: Did you try to remove slash `/` from the end of the link, and send Axios request, like: `axios.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/registration', {` ❓(=

Comment: Yes, I just tried removing slash ```/``` from end of the link now it shows 500 server error.

Comment: This my request data
```
citizenship_num: "9849829046"
confirm: "12345678asd"
contact_num: "9849829046"
email: "user4@gmail.com"
first_name: "user4"
last_name: "Rms"
opt_contact_num: ""
password: "12345678asd"
role_id: "3"
username: "user4"
```

Comment: did anyone found this answer?

Comment: Waiting for the answer.. getting the 400 error while trying to login React-admin, Django API

Answer (score 2):

Still experiencing this same issue 2 years later!

Inspect your error that returns in the catch block:

```
.catch(e => {
                console.log(e.response.data);
            })

/**
{
email: ['This field may not be blank.']
password1: ['This field may not be blank.']
password2: ['This field may not be blank.']
}
*/
```

Oddly, if you are using fetch, the catch block won't be triggered.

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8000/dj-rest-auth/login/', {method: "POST"})
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {console.log(res)})
```

will log the same result to the console

Comment: My bad -- I should have clarified that it seems that the 400 response is the expected behavior, but that it is necessary to inspect the body of the response to retrieve the desired information.